# lxml ignore part of HTML tag

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

Okay, so I've got HTML code like this one:

```
<span class="lista_td_calendar" rel="1617096300">finished</span>
```

And I would like to fetch it using lxml, though there are many spans of this class, and each of them has different `rel` attribute, and I've written something like this:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get(link)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

series = tree.xpath('//span[@class="lista_td_calendar"]/text()')
print(series)
```

Though it doesn't fetch anything, is there ayway to make it undependant from `rel` argument?

Comment: how about just using `.cssselect()` instead of `.xpath`? Like this - `tree.cssselect('span.lista_td_calendar')`

Comment: @sammy And I should print it with `.text_content()`, though it returns epty string for me

Comment: check `page.text` and see if there is the content you want. You might need to check the website and use `selenium`

Comment: Okay, I see what's wrong it's part changed by js, so it's empty on initialization, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the value I was trying to reach was generated by javascript so it's unreachable through request module, using selenium solved the problem

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://blackclover.wbijam.pl/pierwsza_seria-170.html')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('lista_td_calendar')
```